# Search questions with minimum number of favorites

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, search

I think it would be nice to have:

> questions with a minimum number of favorites

as a new search option in the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search), since usually the number of favorites is strongly tied to their importance and helpfulness in a future.

**Example:** `favorites:3 apples oranges`, will perform a normal fruit search but filtering out any questions that do *not* met with the "at least 3 favorites"

Comment: I concur. This is a feature that I've looked for but haven't found a workaround for. This would enable SO to auto build FAQs and knowledge bases without the limitation of specific keyword based searching.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a few queries on data.SE which filter questions with a minimum number of favorites:

- By Tag:

  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372085/posts-with-a-specific-tag-and-a-minimum-number-of-favorites
- By Text:

  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372096/posts-with-specific-text-and-a-minimum-number-of-favorites

Hope they are useful for future reference.